# problem with texcoord at post effect (quad rendering)

Tags: textures, directx11, graphic-effects, post-processing

I have this shader:

```
float4x4 View;

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float2 Position : POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

PS_INPUT VsMain(VS_INPUT _Input)
{
    PS_INPUT Output;

    Output.Position = mul(View, float4(_Input.Position, 0, 1));
    Output.TexCoord = _Input.TexCoord;  

    return Output;
}

float4 PsMain(PS_INPUT _Input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 Color = float4(_Input.TexCoord, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    return Color;
}

technique11 Render
{
    pass P0
    {       
        SetVertexShader(     CompileShader(vs_5_0, VsMain()));
        SetHullShader(       NULL);
        SetDomainShader(     NULL);
        SetGeometryShader(   NULL);
        SetPixelShader(      CompileShader(ps_5_0, PsMain()));
    }
}
```

and this vertices:

```
const float g_QuadVertices[] =
{
//   X     Y     U     V
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

It is a full screen quad and everything is fine. Only my Texcoord is always the same on every vertice? I got a dark yellow picture on my screen! It seems that the pixel shader don't interpolate (u,v between pixels).

The TexCoord inside the pixel shader is always u = 0.5 and v = 0.5.

[image: result on screen]

[image: debugging pixel shader with nsight]

I tried to create my own sampler with:

```
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC SamplerDescription;

SamplerDescription.Filter         = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
SamplerDescription.AddressU       = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
SamplerDescription.AddressV       = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
SamplerDescription.AddressW       = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
SamplerDescription.MipLODBias     = 0.0f;
SamplerDescription.MaxAnisotropy  = 0;
SamplerDescription.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
SamplerDescription.BorderColor[0] = 0;
SamplerDescription.BorderColor[1] = 0;
SamplerDescription.BorderColor[2] = 0;
SamplerDescription.BorderColor[3] = 0;
SamplerDescription.MinLOD         = 0;
SamplerDescription.MaxLOD         = 0;

Res = m_pDevice->CreateSamplerState(&SamplerDescription, &m_pSamplerState);
```

but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the sampler inside the shader, but create an ID3D11SamplerState* outside and upload it while drawing by ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetSampler(slot,count,sampler);
I had the same problem with DX11.

You might create a sampler like this:

```
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
    samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    samplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
    samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 16;
    samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[0] = 0;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[1] = 0;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[2] = 0;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[3] = 0;
    samplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    samplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &mapSampler);
```

Comment: If I create an sampler with CreateSamplerState() I got E_INVALIDARG.

Comment: Please post your sampler description. (The D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC strut)

Comment: D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC SamplerDescription;    ZeroMemory(&SamplerDescription, sizeof(SamplerDescription));

    SamplerDescription.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    SamplerDescription.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    SamplerDescription.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    SamplerDescription.MinLOD = 0;
    SamplerDescription.MaxLOD = 0;

Comment: post edited....

Comment: You don't need to ZeroMemory your samplerdesc, fill out the missing elements instead (not everything might support zero values). And try to modify your maxLod to D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX .

Comment: Ok. The sampler works fine but the output is always the same.

Comment: Is it bound to your pixel shader while rendering? Also, you might want to delete the previous declaration from your shader, and replace it with a new declaration which is like this: SamplerState sampler:register(s0); Where s0 means the first sampler slot. (or set it to a preferred slot)

Comment: I rewrite my shader from an effect to HLSL. Now it works. This problem is very strange.